# How can I reload a Fancybox?

Tags: javascript, ajax, fancybox, reload

I have the newest Fancybox and I just want to update the content of a Ajax Fancybox with a Button in the Fancybox.
Is there any Method in Fancybox which reload the content?

Comment: I don't see why you would need a method on the box itself.  You could just hook up an ajax call to your onclick event on that button and away you go.  Just wrap the Fancybox on a div and refresh the contents of that div after the call is successful.

Comment: I think you missunderstood my question. I don't use ajax, the fancybox use ajax to load the page in the fancybox. And i want to know how i reload the page in the fancybox.

Comment: You want to update the content of a "Fancybox" with an ajax call using a button. Isn't that right?

Comment: Sorry I just want a newline and I clicked Enter.

Comment: Yes thats right, but i want to use Ajax-Implementation of the Fancybox.

Comment: The fancybox has the simplest ajax implementation, you still need to define your own ajax call for that particular button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
                data:
                    {
                        //whatever you need to send back to the server
                        //this could be the id of the element to refresh


                    },
                url: 'your_url_to_send_it_to'
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (result) {
                    //update the element with result
                }
            })


});
```

I've written down a very simple ajax call on a button with id "button". This is exactly what you need in order to refresh the Fancybox element.  There isn't a method you can use within Fancybox itself to perform this, you have to write your own ajax call.  Hope I was of some help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!
I did want to use this method but I think I don't have a other possibility.
I just have one last question.
Do I have to create a tag around the hole content of the fancybox or is there any predefined element which includes all the content of the fancybox?

Comment: I would strongly recommend creating a div element around it, a wrapper. That way you have control of the content inside the div and don't mess around with elements in the Fancybox itself.  Hopefully that guides you in the right direction